# How do I fix Invalid Schema when appending a BigQuery table using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am trying to append data to a table in BigQuery using Pandas and google-cloud-big query.  The problem I am having is I can create a table initially using `if_exists=append` but when I rerun the exact same query, I get an error -

> "pandas_gbq.gbq.InvalidSchema: Please verify that the structure and
>   data types in the DataFrame match the schema of the destination
>   table."

Here is the code I am running:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import pandas_gbq
from google.cloud import bigquery

output = [['Test', 'v1', 'cost_center', '123', date(2020, 1, 31), 30.0],
          ['Test', 'v1', 'cost_center', '345', date(2020, 1, 31), 72.0]]

headers = ['scenario', 'version', 'entity', 'account', 'period', 'amount']
df_output = pd.DataFrame(output, columns=headers)

dataset_table = 'my_dataset'
project_id ='my_project_id'
table_schema = [{'name':'scenario', 'type':'string'},
                {'name':'version', 'type':'string'},
                {'name':'entity', 'type':'string'},
                {'name':'account', 'type':'string'},
                {'name':'period', 'type':'date'},
                {'name':'amount', 'type':'float'}
]
df_output.to_gbq(destination_table=dataset_table, 
                 project_id= project_id, 
                 if_exists='append',
                 table_schema=table_schema)
```

It looks as if this issue has been encountered before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545738/pandas-to-gbq-claims-a-schema-mismatch-while-the-schemas-are-exactly-the-same).  But there is no answer.  Other questions on SO dealt with issues where there was a type difference between the dataframe schema and the BQ table schema.

To simplify the problem further, I tried making all columns have `'type':'String'`, but I get the same error message.

Thank you for the assistance.

Here is a screenshot of the table schema in BQ UI after script runs once.

[image: Screenshot of the table schema in BQ UI]

Comment: Can you share your `pandas` version?

Comment: I am using `Pandas 1.0.3` and `Pandas-gbq 0.13.1`.

Comment: also using `python 3.8.2` on Windows 10 machine

Comment: I conversed with someone maintaining Pandas-gbq.  He suggested I upgrade to version 0.13.2 which should solve the problem.  I did the upgrade, but the problem remains. Current version is now `Panda-gbq 0.13.2`

Comment: i think you should write 'float64' as type for 'amount'. There is no Float type in BigQuery.

Comment: I tried using 'float64' as the type for 'amount, but get same error

Comment: I updated my answer, hope it works for you as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can repro the same error as you and after placing some debug output in pandas library (which you can do the same), when type names are in upper case it works for me

```
table_schema = [{'name':'scenario', 'type':'STRING'},
                {'name':'version', 'type':'STRING'},
                {'name':'entity', 'type':'STRING'},
                {'name':'account', 'type':'STRING'},
                {'name':'period', 'type':'DATE'}, 
                {'name':'amount', 'type':'FLOAT'}
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out the typo in the table_schema.  I have corrected it in the question.  It is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: I have dropped the table in BigQuery and rerun the script trying different means to correct it many times.  Adding 'mode' : 'required' did not resolve issue so I took it back out.

Comment: Could you check BigQuery UI and paste a screenshot of how the table looks like from UI?

Comment: I have added the screenshot to the question section

Comment: Success!  Thank you.  Solution was to make sure types are capital letters.